# Scheduling a Managed Package Class from Anonymous window getting Invalid Type Error

Tags: managed-package, scheduled-apex, scheduled-job

I have a "SchedulableClass" class in a managed package. I want to schedule the class to run for every 5 mins in my org by Anonymous block, Below is the code

```
System.schedule('Schedule Job Name 1',  '0 00 * * * ?', new SchedulableClass());
System.schedule('Schedule Job Name 2',  '0 05 * * * ?', new SchedulableClass());
System.schedule('Schedule Job Name 3',  '0 10 * * * ?', new SchedulableClass());
System.schedule('Schedule Job Name 4',  '0 15 * * * ?', new SchedulableClass());
System.schedule('Schedule Job Name 5',  '0 20 * * * ?', new SchedulableClass());
System.schedule('Schedule Job Name 6',  '0 25 * * * ?', new SchedulableClass());
System.schedule('Schedule Job Name 7',  '0 30 * * * ?', new SchedulableClass());
System.schedule('Schedule Job Name 8',  '0 35 * * * ?', new SchedulableClass());
System.schedule('Schedule Job Name 9',  '0 40 * * * ?', new SchedulableClass());
System.schedule('Schedule Job Name 10', '0 45 * * * ?', new SchedulableClass());
System.schedule('Schedule Job Name 11', '0 50 * * * ?', new SchedulableClass());
System.schedule('Schedule Job Name 12', '0 55 * * * ?', new SchedulableClass());
```

Getting `Invalid type: SchedulableClass`  error. Please let me know where is the issue in my code.

Comment: Have you tried including package namespace in this code? (Like `<namespace>.<apex class>`)

Comment: Yes tried, getting `Type is not visible: PAS.SchedulableClass`

Comment: Is the class and method global for the scheduleable code? You will need the namespace as well

Comment: Looks like the apex class might not be marked as `global`? Note that `public` access modifier in apex will not work. Check the note on `public` access modifier here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_access_modifiers.htm. Also, does the manage package have different versions that can be referenced? Check this out: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_version_settings_packages.htm

Comment: I think that's pretty unambiguous that the problem is visibility - would one of y'all like to post an answer?

Comment: I got a problem like that with a global class a long time ago, the way I solved: clicked compile all classes on Apex Classes page.